# Upload: Failed to Write File to Disk on Images > 1MB

Tags: wordpress, server

My site runs Wordpress 4.6.1. When I upload an image greater than 1MB this error appears

> Upload: Failed to Write File to Disk

This is my server config:

```
root@beta:~# grep --color -R client_max_body_size /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    client_max_body_size 50M;
root@beta:~# GET websitename.net/lainfo.php|egrep 'post_max_size|upload_max_filesize'
<tr><td class="e">post_max_size</td><td class="v">100M</td><td class="v">100M</td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">upload_max_filesize</td><td class="v">100M</td><td class="v">100M</td></tr>
root@beta:~#
```

I checked the following common issues to no avail:

1. hard disk full <-- not full
2. folder chmod <-- works with images under 1MB

Answer (score 1):

Try to enable all this settings:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

Comment: Hi @alex I have this config: *apologies, I don't know how quote code here:

>     root@xxxx:~# curl -s xxx.xxxx.xxx/info.php|egrep -i 'upload_max_filesize|post_max_size|max_execution_time|max_input_time'|sed
> -e 's#<tr><td class="e">##g; s#</td><td class="v">90</td></tr>##g; s#</td><td class="v"># #g'
>     max_execution_time 90
>     max_input_time 90
>     post_max_size 100M 100M</td></tr>
>     upload_max_filesize 100M 100M</td></tr>
>     root@xxxx:~#

Comment: What about PHP `memory_limit` ?

Comment: Also look at WP settings `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT`.

Comment: I have no log with error on memory limit (memory_limit 128M)

Comment: About `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` Not specified, I'm using from php.ini